# content 100% height to window height

Tags: html, css

I want a header on my site with some height, and a footer fixed at page bottom. I have a problem with the content block height.

I want to make the content stretch to the full window height when there is not much content text and stretch to the full height of the content when it is bigger than the window height.

When I set content block to 'height:100%', it goes out of screen (ignoring header block height).

How can I make it stretch to full window height considering height of header?

basic example (how it is now):

http://cssdesk.com/Tcs98

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you want the header to be fixed at the top of the page and the content to scroll independently of the footer and header?

Comment: No. Header and content scrolling when content text is bigger than window height (footer always fixed), and content height fit to window height when amount of content text is small.

Comment: So you don't want the content and header to scroll when the content is smaller than the screen height. Yes?

Comment: yes, just content block supposed to have window height without header height, because it will have own bg color

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to do this with just css. I have a simple three line solution using jQuery if you are interested. The problem is that you can't do CSS conditionally. With the inclusion of a scrip you can check to see if the content is shorter than the body height and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Ok, If I don't find css solution, it will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that there is no way in CSS to say if this element is X tall then this element should be Y tall. [(Not yet that is)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/)

You need to use a script to get the height of the window and compare it to the height of the content.

I use jQuery for this because it is simple and does not take a whole bunch of browser specific checks to work across a lot of browsers:

```
$(function(){
    if($('.content').height() < $(window).height() - 225){
        $('.content').css('height',($(window).height() - 225) + 'px');
    }
});
```

this takes the height of the content at DOM ready and compares it to the height of the Window less the height of the header and footer.

If it is less than the window height less the header and footer (effectively your content area) then it sets the height to that value.

then you need to modify the current CSS and remove the 100% height of the content and add 25px of padding at the bottom to make room for the footer.

[Here is an example of large content.](http://jsfiddle.net/WZvzg/2/) and [Here is an example of small content](http://jsfiddle.net/WZvzg/1/)

of course this is a simple example and does not handle the window re-sizing.

EDIT: After spending the day thinking about it, I realized it would not be that much harder to make it completely responsive.

```
var initialHeight, contentHeight;

$(function(){    
    initialHeight = $('.content').height();
    contentHeight = $(window).height() - 225;

    if(initialHeight < contentHeight ){
        $('.content').css('height',contentHeight + 'px');
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        contentHeight = $(window).height() - 225;
        if(initialHeight < contentHeight){
            $('.content').css('height',contentHeight + 'px');    
        }else{
            $('.content').css('height',initialHeight + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

Using the above code, the window and content height do not matter; it will always resize to fit the 'content' area.

You define a 'content' area as the amount of 'window' that is not occupied by the footer and header. Then you take the height of the content element when the window loads the first time. If the content area gets bigger than the content element, then you set a new height that matches the content area, if it gets smaller, then you set the height equal to what it started out as.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aK9Lk/)